# cobol - java console output

Tags: java, console, cobol, logging

HI,

I have a jar using log4j, it has only a file appender.

If I run it from eclipse or from windows command line it works fine, but if I call the jar from cobol the logger is printed in the console too.

I guess cobol is the problem, how could I deactivate the console log

thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a classloader issue if the environment has its own log4j implementation which is called by your code instead of the log4j you bring with you.

Add details about your environment.

Comment: Which detail do you need? I don´t know anything about cobol language, but I know the version is 'ServerExpresSp 4.0' and use java 1.4. This is the cobol the declaration: 'AGRSCO <myClass> AAM0001' and the call invocation is somethisng like 'AGRSCO*    INVOKE ENTRADA-JC "new" RETURNING ENTRADA-JR                 AAM0001'. Thx a lot!!!

Comment: Sounds like Micro Focus Cobol, which I am unfamiliar with.  Sorry.